# How to create a tree in C++?

Tags: c++, data-structures, tree, graph-theory

I want to create a tree in `C++`. I have the parent-child relationships and the number of nodes and I want to store this tree somehow. For example, if I have a graph, I can store it with adjacency lists, or using a vector of vectors, or a matrix of adjacency. But how about trees?

For example, I have **9** nodes and **9-1=8** parent-child relationships: **7-2, 7-3, 7-4, 3-5, 3-6, 5-8, 5-9, 6-1**. I want to store this tree, for example to calculate the longest path from the oldest parent (**7**) to a child (in this case is **7-3-5-8** or **7-3-5-9** and the path has the length of **4**).

Comment: Any acyclic undirected connected graph is a tree. You can store a tree the same way you store a graph.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your graph is directed and you don't know the range of the numbers for the nodes, I suggest you use `map<int, vector<int> >` as your adjacency list:

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    map< int, vector<int> > adj_list;

    int edges;
    cin >> edges;
    for ( int i=0; i<edges; ++i ){
        int u, v;
        cin>>u>>v;
        adj_list[u].push_back(v);
        //adj_list[v].push_back(u); // uncomment this line if your graph is directed
    }

    for ( auto it = adj_list.begin(); it != adj_list.end(); ++it ){
        const auto& children = it->second;
        cout << "children of " << it->first << " is:" << endl;
        for ( int i=0; i < children.size(); ++i ){
            cout << children[i] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

**input**

```
8
7 2
7 3
7 4
3 5
3 6
5 8
5 9
6 1
```

**output**

```
children of 3 is:
5 6 
children of 5 is:
8 9 
children of 6 is:
1 
children of 7 is:
2 3 4
```

Using this structure every *key* of the `map` holds the adjacency list of that node in the form of `vector<int>`. It means you can access the children of node *1* by traversing `adj_list[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

I would store a tree by having a node contain a vector of (smart) pointers to nodes.  For example:

```
struct tree_node
{
    int value;
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<tree_node>> children;
};
```

Comment: And how can I use one specific node and the relationships of it?

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

> if I have a graph, I can store it with adjacency lists, or using a vector of vectors, or a matrix of adjacency. But how about trees?

but [a tree is a type of graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)).

There's even a specific example on (family) trees in the [Boost.Graph](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html) documentation for its adjacency list.